# Overcoming 'Limit Ad Tracking' - iOS

Tags: ios, ads, facebook-audience-network

As I understand from [Facebook Audience Network FAQs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq), ads will not be served if user has enabled "Limit Ad Tracking".

What can I do to overcome it? Is there a way to know that the user has enabled "Limit Ad Tracking" and in this case what other type of ads can be presented?

Comment: Respect the wishes of your users.

Comment: @gnasher729, I respect their wish not to receive targeted ads. Now, how do I show then integrated ads?

Comment: I believe the term you wanted here was "adapt to" rather than "overcome." "Overcome" makes it sound like you want to ignore the user's request. Look at `FBAdViewDelegate`. You should receive an error in `adView:didFailWithError:` if there's a problem and you can choose something else to present at that time. (I have no background in FB Ads; I'm just reading the docs, which is why I'm not making this an answer.)

Comment: @RobNapier, You can make it an answer. I'll mark it as correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [`FBAdViewDelegate`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.22/protocol/FBAdViewDelegate/). You should receive an error in `adView:didFailWithError:` if there's a problem and you can choose something else to present at that time.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're referring to the following from the FAQ:

> **Can users in my app opt out from seeing Facebook ads?**
>
> We will not serve ads to people that have advertising opt-outs enabled
>   on their iOS and Android devices.

"Limit Ad Tracking" is not opting out of ads. It simply tells the advertiser to not track the ads for that user. It means that the advertiser should not deliver targeted ads.

As of iOS 9.3, there is no setting in iOS to opt out of ads. Perhaps this is in the FAQ to cover any future setting.

Comment: But all Facebook Audience Network Ads are targeted ads. If I don't receive those, I don't receive ads at all

Comment: Found this under [User Security and Privacy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/targeting): "If we detect that a device has Limit Ad Tracking enabled, we will not serve an ad based on that device's activity on third-party websites and apps." While, I'm not sure that is completely in line with Apple's policies, it is evidence that the SDK falls back to a less targeted version of an ad if the user has "Limit ad tracking" on.